# ¿Como se inserta un botón en un email body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Tengo esta estructura para enviar correo para restaurar la contraseña, pero no quiero hacerlo por medio de un enlace sino con un botón con el enlace, no se como crear el boton

```
 correo.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtMailClave.Text));
    correo.Subject = "Restaurar contraseña";
    correo.Body = "<!DOCTYPE html> " +
            "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" +
            "<head>" +
            "<title>Email</title>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body style=\"font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;\">" +
            "Si solicitaste un restablecimiento de contraseña para tu cuenta, haz clic en" + "<br />" + "el botón que aparece a continuación. Si no solicitaste esto, ignora este" + "<br />" + "correo electrónico." + "<br />" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>";
```

Comment: a tener en cuenta:
https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

Comment: Mi amigo te puedo recomendar que mejor investiges un poco de mail sql server y envies el correo desde ahi y ese correo lo pongas en u store procedure y en tu web solo cuando queires mandar o presionar algo un buton que se ejecute el store procedure

Answer (score 0):

No se puede usar un HTML boton normal? Como asi:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tuURL" value="Lo que dic el boton">
```